# Closed-form analytical solution for the variance of the minimum-variance portfolio?

Tags: portfolio-optimization, modern-portfolio-theory, mean-variance

The portfolio weights vector of the minimum-variance portfolio has a closed-form analytical solution,

$$\boldsymbol{w} = \frac{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1} \boldsymbol{1} }{\boldsymbol{1}^\top \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1} \boldsymbol{1}}$$

but is there a direct calculation for the same portfolio's variance $\sigma_p^2$?

Given that $ \sigma_p^2 = \boldsymbol{w^\top \Sigma w}$, what is the simplification of

\begin{aligned}
\sigma_p^2 & = \left( \frac{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1} \boldsymbol{1} }{\boldsymbol{1}^\top \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1} \boldsymbol{1}}\right)^\top \cdot \boldsymbol{\Sigma} \cdot \frac{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1} \boldsymbol{1} }{\boldsymbol{1}^\top \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1} \boldsymbol{1}} \\ & = \frac{\boldsymbol{1} ^\top(\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^\top)^{-1}}{\boldsymbol{1} ^\top\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1} \boldsymbol{1} } \cdot \boldsymbol{\Sigma} \cdot \frac{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1} \boldsymbol{1} }{\boldsymbol{1}^\top \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1} \boldsymbol{1}} \\ & = ?
\end{aligned}

$$$$

How about the maximum-Sharpe ratio portfolio's variance as well?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question fully. Isn't any portfolio variance defined as $\sigma_P^2 = w' \Sigma w$? So once you have your weights, the variance should be easy?

Comment: I'ved edited with detail

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let

\begin{align}
a&\equiv \mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\mathbf{1}\\
b&\equiv \mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\mu}\\
c&\equiv \boldsymbol{\mu}^T\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\mu}
\end{align}

Then
\begin{align}
\mathrm{E(minVarPortfolio)}& = \frac{b}{a}\\
\mathrm{V(minVarPortfolio)}& = \frac{1}{a}\\
\mathrm{E(TangencyPortfolio)}& = \frac{c}{b}\\
\mathrm{V(TangencyPortfolio)}& = \frac{c}{b^2}\\
\mathrm{Cov(MVP,Tangency)}& = \frac{1}{a}\\
\end{align}

Effectively, the covariance between *any* efficient portfolio and the MVP is $1/a$.

Comment: does the last sentence lead to analytical solutions for the many frontier portfolios that lie between the min-var and max-Sharpe, and their respective portfolio moments?

Comment: Yes, you can analytically derive the volatility of an efficient portfolio $\sigma_p$ as a function of its expected return, $\mu$, i.e. $\sigma(\mu)$. This holds only for equality constraint portfolio optimization, though.

Comment: why are $\mathrm{V(minVarPortfolio)}$ and $\mathrm{Cov(MVP,Tangency)}$ both equal to $\frac{1}{a}$?

Comment: That's basic algebra. $w_{MVP}=\frac{\Sigma^{-1}\mathbf{1}}{\mathbf{1}^T\Sigma^{-1}\mathbf{1}}$ and $w_{T}=\frac{\Sigma^{-1}\mathbf{\mu}}{\mathbf{1}^T\Sigma^{-1}\mathbf{\mu}}$. Then the covariance is $w_{MVP}^T\Sigma w_{T}$ which equals $1/a$.

Comment: why would pre- and post-multiplying the covariance matrix with two different portfolio weight vectors, as in $w_{MVP}^\top \Sigma w_{T}$, give their covariance?

Comment: That’s simply the definition of covariance.

Comment: do the components $a$, $b$ and $c$ assume asset returns or portfolio returns are normally distributed, given that they all contain the sample covariance matrix? Or is there no difference as to  $a$, $b$ and $c$'s application in normal and non-normality settings?

Comment: @develarist, I notice that you ask many questions around (multivariate) normality, linear algebra and such. If you are such inclined, I suggest you study the materials on LinAlg in portfolio optimisation, e.g. here https://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ424/portfolioTheoryMatrix.pdf

Comment: I've had that file for several years but it doesn't contain the words Gauss or normal really. that's why I'm asking about the coverage that $a$, $b$ and $c$ provide

Comment: @develarist isn’t it specified on p1?

Comment: if returns are assumed $\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ for the entire document, then $a$, $b$ and $c$ only apply in the Gaussian case, not when returns follow non-normality

Comment: I think I understand what you want to say. Technically, it really doesn't matter *how* returns are distributed: As long as the first two moments exist, the Markowitz approach can be used to form mean/variance optimal portfolios. If the agent exhibits quadratic utility, such a  portfolio would be expected utility maximizing. For general distributions and general utility functions, of course, the Markowitz approach is not optimal in a utility sense.

Answer (score 8):

A few more steps beyond your last equation gives the answer.

With $C = \mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\mathbf{1}$, we have

$$\sigma_P^2 = [C^{-1} \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\mathbf{1}]^T \mathbf{\Sigma} [C^{-1}\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\mathbf{1}] = C^{-2}\mathbf{1}^T(\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1})^T\mathbf{\Sigma} \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\mathbf{1}$$

Since  $[(\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1})^T\mathbf{\Sigma}^T]^T = \mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1} = \mathbf{I} = \mathbf{I}^T$, it follows that $(\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1})^T= (\mathbf{\Sigma}^T)^{-1}$.  As the  covariance matrix is symmetric, this implies $(\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1})^T= \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}$.

Thus,

$$\sigma_P^2 = C^{-2}\mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\mathbf{\Sigma} \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\mathbf{1}= C^{-2}\mathbf{1}^T\ \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\mathbf{1}= C^{-2}C = \frac{1}{ \mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\mathbf{1}}$$

Comment: can  $\frac{1}{ \mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\mathbf{1}}$ be reduced to a non-fraction such as a simplified version of $(\mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\mathbf{1})^{-1}$? I am not familiar with matrix fraction operations

Comment: @develarist: The term $C= \mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\mathbf{1}$ is a number -- it is the product of a $1\times n$ vector, an $n \times n$ matrix, and an $n \times 1$ vector.  So $C^{-1} = 1/C$. (That is how I factored out $C^{-2}$ in the first step.)

Comment: wasn't my question. how can 1/$C$ be reduced to a non-fraction

Comment: The quadratic form $C= \mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\mathbf{1}$ is the sum of the elements of the inverse matrix $\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}$.  An element $s_{ij}$ of $\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}$ is of the form $s_{ij} = \frac{C_{ji}}{\det \mathbf{\Sigma}}$ where $C_{ji}$ is the cofactor -- determinant of the submatrix of $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ obtained by deleting row j and column i. Hence, $\frac{1}{C} = \frac{\det\mathbf{\Sigma}}{\sum_i \sum_j C_{ij}}$

Comment: In the $2 \times 2$ case we get $\frac{1}{C} = \frac{\sigma_{11}\sigma_{22} - \sigma_{12}^2}{\sigma_{11} + \sigma_{22} - 2\sigma_{12}}$ .

Comment: it's ok. they're still fractions

Comment: Does $\frac{1}{C} = \frac{\det\mathbf{\Sigma}}{\sum_i \sum_j C_{ij}} =  \det \mathbf{\Sigma} (\sum_i \sum_j C_{ij})^{-1}$ qualify as a non-fraction? I can't simplify it any further.

Comment: wonder if the tangency portfolio derivation could be edited into the answer as a second part

Comment: wonder if you can also answer this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3904562/simplify-a-fraction-of-vectors-and-matrices-of-form-fracb2a-cdot-c