# Mathematical proof of out-of-sample disappointment in portfolio performance being a function of a portfolio's variance

Tags: portfolio-optimization, modern-portfolio-theory, mathematics, mean-variance, performance-evaluation

- The minimum-variance portfolio is considered more optimal than the maximum Sharpe ratio (tangency) portfolio on the grounds that its in-sample performance is less likely to disappoint out-of-sample.

Out-of-sample disappointment refers to the difference between performance predicted in-sample and *actual* performance attained out-of-sample.

- It is also proven by definition that the minimum-variance portfolio's *returns* (a time series) have [lower variance](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/59145/closed-form-analytical-solution-for-the-variance-of-the-minimum-variance-portfol) than the variance of the maximum Sharpe portfolio's *returns series*.

Is the minimum-variance portfolio's out-of-sample performance more consistent with its in-sample performance *because* it has lower variance than the tangency portfolio? In other words, **is the in-and-out-of-sample discrepancy of mean-variance portfolios *a function of* their defined variance?**

If so, how can this be shown mathematically? How can it be proven that the minimum-variance portfolio will always have lower out-of-sample disappointment than the tangency portfolio, similar to how it can be mathematically proved that it has lower variance? Put a different way, how can we show that the minimum-variance portfolio's performance predicted in-sample *will always be more consistent with* its actual out-of-sample performance *than* the maximum Sharpe portfolio's in-versus-out-of-sample performance consistency?

Comment: Handwaving here: the metric for 'disappointment' is different in the two cases. The minvar portfolio is built without using any estimate of expected returns, and it's in-sample 'performance' is estimated the same way. The Markowitz portfolio has to estimate the vector of mean returns, and is scored in-sample by the same, adding more noise.

Comment: See also [Ao, Li, Zheng](http://wp.lancs.ac.uk/fofi2018/files/2018/03/FoFI-2018-0055-Mengmeng-Ao.pdf), [El Karoui](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1291126965), [Pav](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.5936). Tangentially related is [Paulsen & Sohl](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.06186), and [Pav](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.06171).

Comment: those are known. let's go past that.