# Efficient frontier portfolio's analytical solution for a given expected return $r$

Tags: portfolio-optimization, finance-mathematics, modern-portfolio-theory, reference-request, mean-variance

$$\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{w}(r) = \frac{r\mathbf\Sigma^{-1} \boldsymbol{\mu}}{\boldsymbol{\mu}^{\top}  \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\mu}}
\end{equation} 
$$
is the closed-form analytical solution for the portfolio weight vector of any portfolio along the efficient frontier, whose expected return level is some scalar value $r$. It appears in a 2010s article without citation so it must've been introduced much earlier.

Which source first derived this solution, as well as the analytical solutions for its mean and variance, $\mu_p[\boldsymbol{w}(r)], \sigma_p[\boldsymbol{w}(r)]$? (not to be confused with the [minimum-variance and maximum Sharpe portfolio solutions](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/59145/closed-form-analytical-solution-for-the-variance-of-the-minimum-variance-portfol))

Comment: Hi, could you please explain more in detail what you define $w$ to be? It is a vector of weight? It does not sum to 1, then, no? Also: have you already read the papers by Markowitz anf others? Where have you already looked for information? Where did you get *that* result from? That would be a helpful starting point for us - for me at least :)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Kermittfrog's comment, that this only works if you do not impose any budget constraint (in the sense that your weights sum up to one). Other than that, I am sorry that I can not precisely answer your question where it was first derived (tbh: I am not even sure if it was explicity derived at all somewhere because it simply follows from the very definition of a target-return constraint optimziation problem). In brief:

Let $\mu$ be a $n$-dimensional vector that contains the single-asset returns, and $\Sigma$ the corresponding $n \times n$ covariance matrix. Moreover, let $\mathbf{w}$ be a $n$-dimensional vector that assigns the portfolio weights to the $n$ individual assets. (Here we do not impose summation to unity, see comment above!) Furthermore, express by $r$ the target return an investor expects to achieve on her *portfolio* (thus, $r$ is a scalar). In other words, the optimal solution must in addition satisfy $r = \mu^{T} \mathbf{w}$, where superscript $T$ denotes a vector/matrix transpose.

Now, we seek to minimize (for mathematical convenience: half of) the portfolio variance, which is given by $\mathbf{w}^{T}\Sigma\mathbf{w}$. And we will minimize it under the target return restriction presented above. As we have formulated it as an equality constraint, we can use the **Lagrangian method** to solve this problem. Defining the Lagrangian multiplier $\lambda$, we can write the first-order condition of the optimization problem (with respect to the weight vector) as follows:

$$ \Sigma \mathbf{w} - \lambda \mu = \mathbf{0} $$

Note that $\mathbf{0}$ describes the all-zero vector of dimension $n$. Solving this for $\mathbf{w}$ is easy, and defining by $\Sigma^{-1}$ the inverse of our covariance matrix, we obtain that:

$$ \mathbf{w} = \Sigma^{-1} \lambda \mu$$

Moreover, recall our optimization constraint, which will help us to find $\lambda$; it reads $ r = \mu^{T} \mathbf{w} $. If you plug in the solution for $\mathbf{w}$ and rearrange, you will get that $\lambda = \dfrac{r}{\mu^{T} \Sigma^{-1} \mu}$.

Clearly, you see that this Lagrangian "slack" parameter depends on your choice of target return, $r$. Plugging this Lambda back into our weight solution, you obtain the proposed result:

$$ \mathbf{w}(r) = \dfrac{r \Sigma^{-1} \mu}{\mu^{T} \Sigma^{-1} \mu}  $$.

Finally, in a similar fashion proposed in the answer to your other post ([Closed-form analytical solution for the variance of the minimum-variance portfolio?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/59145)), once you have your ($r$-dependent) weights, the ($r$-dependent) mean and variance of the portfolio follow therefrom.

Comment: So the analytical moments are the minimum-variance portfolio's moment solutions except multiplied by $r$?

Comment: I don't think that this is generally true

Comment: why not, given that $\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{w}_{MV}= \frac{\mathbf\Sigma^{-1} \boldsymbol{\mu}}{\boldsymbol{\mu}^{\top}  \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\mu}}
\end{equation}$, whereas $\mathbf{w}(r) = \dfrac{r \Sigma^{-1} \mu}{\mu^{T} \Sigma^{-1} \mu}$?

Comment: It should be $ \mathbf{w}_{MVP} = \dfrac{\Sigma^{-1} \mathbf{1}}{\mathbf{1}^{T} \Sigma^{-1} \mathbf{1}}  $.

Comment: Hi @develarist, if your question is solved by this answer, please consider accepting it