# Correlation between mean-variance efficient portfolios

Tags: modern-portfolio-theory, correlation, mean-variance, covariance, portfolio-selection

If the [covariance solution](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/59145/closed-form-analytical-solution-for-the-variance-of-the-minimum-variance-portfol/59149#59149) between the returns series of the minimum-variance portfolio ($A$) and any other portfolio along the efficient frontier ($B$) is

$$Cov_{A, B} = \frac{1}{\mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\mathbf{1}}$$
What is the derivation of the closed-form analytical solution for the correlation between those portfolios, $\rho_{A, B}=?$

Comment: Hi @develarist, why don't you simply plug in all your portfolios (MVP, Tangency, target-return) into the formulas for correlation and see what drops out? Can you show where your intuition breaks or what component you are missing?

Comment: Hint: What is the optimal weight vector given a target return $M$? Plug that into the (co)variance formula $w(M)^T\Sigma w_{MVP}$. Simplify as much as possible knowing the definitions $a,b,c$. That should get you somewhere, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just divide covariance by the square roots of the two variances. In this case you would want
$$
\frac{1/a}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{a}\frac{c}{b^2}}},
$$
which takes value
$$
\frac{|1^{\top}\Sigma^{-1}\mu|}{\sqrt{(1^{\top}\Sigma^{-1}1)(\mu^{\top}\Sigma^{-1}\mu)}}.
$$

Comment: I also got the same answer last month

Comment: @develarist the good thing about math is that it doesn't go stale.

Comment: I think that this answer does not imply the  correlation between *any* portfolio and the MVP.

Comment: Sorry, bad English: I think the question asks for the correlation between any portfolio on the frontier and the MVP, not (only) the Tangency portfolio.